# Slick slider cropped images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I use click slider http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/, main display size for slider is 1920 px, but if size becomes smaller images become cropped.
here is my code

```
<div id = "main-slider">
  <div class = "main-slider__slide">
    <div class = "main-slider__slide_img">
      <img src="" alt = "">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I think better to see on the url http://evrika.tests1.enlight.studio/ because plugin ads lots of additional html and css

```
$('#main-slider').slick({
    dots: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    arrows: false,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '0px',
});
```

[image: here is for 1920px]

[image: and here is for 500px]

How can I make images centered?

Comment: A working code example would be useful

Comment: @Levano it is a plugin and it adds lots of html, but I try to show